# Angular DevExtreme grid behavior

Tags: devextreme, devextreme-angular

I am using this [grid](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/CustomEditors/Angular/Light/)

I have a button(Yes) button outside the grid.

When I enter a value in the textbox and don't tab out and click on the button, the value I entered is showing as null.

If I enter a value, tab out and click Yes, I can see the value. But when I go back and change the value in the textbox and don't tab out, and click on the button, Old value is showing and it is not picking the new value.

How can I fix this behavior? and get the value in the textbox without tab out?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the cell editing mode this could be helpful check this [support ticket](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t606811/dxdatagrid-does-not-update-its-data-on-focusing-out-a-cell-when-the-cell-editing-mode-is).
You need to manually save the grid using saveEditData() on button click